# How to Send Key Events As Words

Tags: android, keyevent

I need to send key events as words instead button 
for example instead of this 
    Instrumentation m_Instrumentation = new Instrumentation();
    m_Instrumentation.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_D );
i want it to be like this 
    Instrumentation m_Instrumentation = new Instrumentation();
    m_Instrumentation.sendKeyDownUpSync("Hello" );

Comment: Are you looking for `m_Instrumentation.sendStringSync("String goes here")` ?

Comment: Yup  That What I mean

Comment: But As Key Events Like Send A Whole Word As key Event

Comment: Make a function that has a char as an argument and returns the corresponding `KeyEvent` then have a function to loop through a string as a char array and have it press each button.

Comment: is there any example code

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments by Joseph Evans, create a method to loop through your word and send the corresponding `KeyEvent` - see code below

```
public class InstrumentationHelper {

    public static void sendKeyEventsFor(String word) {

        Instrumentation instrumentation = new Instrumentation();

        KeyCharacterMap mKeyCharacterMap =
                KeyCharacterMap.load(KeyCharacterMap.VIRTUAL_KEYBOARD);

        KeyEvent[] events = mKeyCharacterMap.getEvents(word.toCharArray());

        for (KeyEvent keyEvent : events) {
            instrumentation.sendKeyDownUpSync(keyEvent.getKeyCode());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry for late reply in general will i need any special permission or root for this code

Comment: No special permissions needed.

Comment: So  Word = my word to send to the keyboard

Comment: wouldn't that need  injection permission